# The order of li(x)

Tags: integration, logarithms, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

So I've been investigating $\mathrm{li}(x)$, that is the logarithmic integral function.

I am unsure if this is true, but it seems as if $\mathrm{li}(x) = O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

Specifically, it seems as if for $x$ sufficiently large, there exists an $M>0$, such that

$$|\mathrm{li}(x)|< M\left|\left(\frac x{\log x}\right)\right|.$$

[Wolfram Alpha seems to agree with me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=li%28x%29%20%3C%2030%28x%2Flogx%29), although I cannot be sure if this holds for all $x$.

I would like to prove this behavior myself, and so would rather have hints regarding how I could prove that $\mathrm{li}(x) = O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$ rather than proofs themselves as answers.

Comment: Why, you may find the ratio at infinity using the L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you try to find

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm{li}(x)}{\frac{x}{\log x}}$$

using L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: One could also note that the two functions are asymptotically bounded to the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ , so they must be asymptotically bounded to each other. But how does limit this imply the OP?

Comment: I have proved this using L'Hospital's rule, as you suggested. Am I right in saying now that all that is needed to show that $\mathrm{li}(x) = O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$ , is the reverse triangle inequality?

Comment: @LinusS. With this limit being $L$, you know that, for a large enough $x$, you have $$\frac{\mathrm{li}(x)}{\frac{x}{\log x}}< L + \epsilon$$ and multiplying the inequality gives the OP what he needs (knowing that all the factors here are positive for a large enough $x$.

Comment: @moorish I don't know what you mean by the reverse triangle inequality...

Comment: @5xum Using the fact that $|x|-|y| < |x-y|$ we can prove that $\mathrm{li}(x) = O\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$ is what I am saying. Of course we need to multiply the inequality like you suggested, before we use this fact.

Comment: @moorish Oh, yes. Well, you don't really need to operate with absolute values, everything you have is positive...

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the “european” definition $$\textrm{Li}\left(x\right)=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log\left(t\right)}=\textrm{li}\left(x\right)-\textrm{li}\left(2\right)
 $$ and integrating by parts we have $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log\left(t\right)}=\left.\frac{t}{\log\left(t\right)}\right|_{2}^{x}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}=$$ $$=\frac{x}{\log\left(x\right)}-\frac{2}{\log\left(2\right)}+\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}$$ and note that $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log^{2}\left(t\right)}\leq\frac{1}{\log\left(2\right)}\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dt}{\log\left(t\right)}.
 $$

Answer (score 2):

x
p

+
 x
p2

+
 x
p3

+ ···
1
where [t] denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to t. It immediately follows that
x! = 
p≤x
p[x/p]+[x/p2]+···
and
log(x!) = 
p≤x
x
p

+
 x
p2

+
 x
p3

+ ···
log(p).
Now log(x!) is asymptotic to x log(x) by Stirling’s asymptotic formula, and, since squares,
cubes, ... of primes are comparatively rare, and [x/p] is almost the same as x/p, one may
easily infer that
x

p≤x
log(p)
p = x log(x) + O(x)
from which one can deduce that π(x) is of order x
log(x) . T

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write questions/answers, since it gets more readable for all of us...

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.